# ExifInterface returns wrong orientation (because it stores multiple conflicting attributes)

Tags: android, android-camera, jpeg, orientation

I'm writing an Android app which pulls photos from the gallery.  I discovered that some photos, e.g. a panorama taken in a left direction by a Galaxy S7, are output by the built-in camera app as a "non-normalised jpeg" file, meaning that the image is upside down (or even vertical for a landscape panorama on a Galaxy S5), but it contains instructions in the EXIF data that the viewer should fix it up.

So I read up on ExifInterface and I implemented code to normalise the images:

```
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(file.toString());
                int orig = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);
                if (orig != -1 && orig != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL) {
                    orientation = orig;
                    exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, String.valueOf(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL));
                    exif.saveAttributes();
                }
```

...

```
        Matrix matrix = null;
        if (orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL) {
            matrix = new Matrix();
            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:   matrix.postRotate(90); break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:  matrix.postRotate(180); break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:  matrix.postRotate(-90); break;
            }
        }
```

...
etc

However, on a Galaxy S7, my code fails to work.  After some debugging and delving into system source-code, I discovered that the ExifInterface object stores multiple conflicting values for the "Orientation" attribute, and it was returning the wrong one.  The correct value (i.e. 3) is stored in exif.mAttributes[4] (does this correspond to IFD_THUMBNAIL_TAGS group?) and the incorrect value (i.e. 1) is stored in exif.mAttributes[0] (does this correspond to IFD_TIFF_TAGS?).  So 'exif' reported that it's ORIENTATION_NORMAL but the image loads upside-down, and my matrix code is not called.

What is the recommended solution, or any solution to this problem?

Comment: (1) What is the orientation of the image in the JPEG stream? i.e. minus whatever EXIF is saying. (2) Who is doing the rotation of the image? The library based upon EXIF? Your application? (3) Have you run an an EXIF dump on the JPEG stream? Does it show something different from what your ExifInterface objects show?

Comment: The image is upside-down, i.e. rotated 180 degrees.  The EXIF says both "1" (ORIENTATION_NORMAL) and "3" (ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180).

Comment: The question then would be where the multiple tags are coming from. It is possible that the camera is writing multiple orientation tags into the APP1 marker. Have you run some dump program that will interpret EXIF tags on your JPEG stream?

Comment: I don't know what an APP1 marker is, but it's pretty much confirmed that the built-in camera app is writing multiple orientation tags into the EXIF area, judging by the fact that I see multiple tags parsed, in the different "groups".

Comment: What you want to confirm is that there are dupicate tags in the APP1 marker (and not something happening in the decoder). APP1 is the marker that makes it an EXIF file. There are utilities out there that will do this.